# How can I make a datagridview live connected to an access database stored locally in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I would like it so when I delete/edit a record from the datagridview, it will automatically delete/edit the access database file. Here is a snippet of my code which loads the database into the datagridview.

```
Public Function dbConnect() As Boolean
    Try
        cn = New OleDbConnection(DataBasePath)
        cn.Open()
        'MessageBox.Show("is work ")

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to open the database: " & ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

Private Function GetOrders() As DataTable
    Dim dtOrders As New DataTable
    dbConnect()
    Dim SQLCMD As New OleDbCommand
    SQLCMD.Connection = cn
    SQLCMD.CommandText = "Select * From [OrdersTbl]"
    dtOrders.Load(SQLCMD.ExecuteReader())
    Return dtOrders
End Function

Private Sub EditOrdersForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    OrdersDataGrid.DataSource = GetOrders()
End Sub
```

How can I make it so that changes are saved to the local file.

Comment: Look into using DataAdapters and use a BindingSource as the Datagrid DataSource. Use the DataAdapter FILL command to get your orders DataTable.  Set that as the BindingSource datasource.  When you want to save, use the DataAdapter Update command with your orders datatable and that will update your database with the changes you make in the DataGrid

Comment: Check if my answer helps you handle this issue and if it helps, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If not, please provide more details here.

Answer (score 0):

I have a datagridview and a button on the form. Here's the code you can refer to:

```
Private dt As DataTable = New DataTable
Private da As OleDbDataAdapter
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("your connection string")
    connection.Open()
    Dim cmdTxt As String = "SELECT * FROM yourTable"
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(New OleDbCommand(cmdTxt, connection))
    Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Fill(dt)
    Dim source As BindingSource = New BindingSource With {
                                    .DataSource = dt
                                  }
    DataGridView1.DataSource = source
    connection.Close()
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DataGridView1.EndEdit()
    da.Update(dt)
End Sub
```

Every time you want to update database from your datagridview, just click the button.